# deselect matrix columns using subsed and !grepl functions

Tags: grepl, deselect

I have a single cell RNA sequencing matrix 'dta' with some cells named with KK00 (KK00.xx).
I would like to deselect all these cells.
So I wrote `dta.s <-subset(dta, !grepl('KK00',colnames(dta)))`

It didn't give error but it seems KK00.xx cells are still there when I check by `table(sapply(strsplit(colnames(dta.s), "\\."), function(x) {x[1]}))`.

Can someone help?

Best

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.

I changed this

```
dta.s <-subset(dta, !grepl('KK00',colnames(dta)))
```

to this

```
dta <- dta[,!grepl('KK00.', colnames(dta))]
```

Now, it works.